# SQL (SSMS) join all records from one table and second table but exclude 'duplicates' from second

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm having an issue where I went all records in Table B and any non matching records in Table A but it's bringing back the matching records in Table A. There is another left join to an additional table which is brought in for reference only.

I'm using SSMS v18.

So ID will be on Table A and Table B. There will be multiple records of this ID on A and B but I don't want the duplicate records if date/time and ID is the same in Table A and in Table B.

e.g. - I've simplified the query I'm using below.

```
Select
    a.id
    a.datetime
    a.emp_id
    c.team_id
From 
    table_a as a
Left Join 
    table_b as b On a.id = b.id
                 And a.datetime <> b.datetime
Left Join 
    table_c On a.emp_id = c.emp_id
```

As there isn't NULLs I don't think I can use that. I don't believe a full outer join will return what I need.

Is there a method is solve this? A union query solution will not work as Table A and Table B do not have the same columns/column names.

Please let me know if more information is required.

**EDIT - Additional**
Apologies but now there's been a change of requirement where I now need to remove the matching records rather than remove just the duplicates. Is there a way around this?

**Additional - Data Examples**

**Table A:**

```
+----+------------------+--------+
| Id |     Datetime     | emp_id |
+----+------------------+--------+
|  1 | 20/04/2021 10:30 | a      |
|  1 | 20/04/2021 11:15 | a      |
|  2 | 21/04/2021 12:10 | b      |
|  2 | 21/04/2021 13:20 | b      |
|  2 | 22/04/2021 15:30 | c      |
|  3 | 23/04/2021 09:45 | d      |
|  4 | 23/04/2021 14:35 | e      |
+----+------------------+--------+
```

**Table B:**

```
+----+------------------+-------------+
| Id |     Datetime     | other_field |
+----+------------------+-------------+
|  1 | 20/04/2021 10:30 | x           |
|  2 | 21/04/2021 13:20 | y           |
|  4 | 23/04/2021 14:35 | z           |
+----+------------------+-------------+
```

**Desired Output:**

```
+----+------------------+--------+---------+
| Id |     Datetime     | emp_id | team_id |
+----+------------------+--------+---------+
|  1 | 20/04/2021 11:15 | a      | team_01 |
|  2 | 21/04/2021 12:10 | b      | team_02 |
|  2 | 22/04/2021 15:30 | c      | team_01 |
|  3 | 23/04/2021 09:45 | d      | team_02 |
+----+------------------+--------+---------+
```

So the duplicate ID & Datetime in Table B does not show in final output (regardless of any other fields)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  For instance, your problem description doesn't mention TableC.

Comment: If you can create example data for each table, then you're able to demonstrate the behaviour and results you want for various cases.  At present it's too generic and ambiguous...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

You seem to need a right join instead of a left join. A left join will bring back all rows in table A, and all rows in table B which match the condition which you provided. You seem to want all in table B, which requires a right join.

I know some developers who have an aversion to right joins, if you feel that way, you can simply switch the order of the tables in your query to have table B listed first, left join to table A. I feel that the first solution is the easier one, though you need to be comfortable with it.

Here are my solutions, listed in the order in which I mentioned above.

```
Select
     a.id
    ,a.datetime
    ,a.emp_id
    ,c.team_id
From 
    table_a as a
RIGHT Join  -- here is my change 
    table_b as b On a.id = b.id
                 And a.datetime <> b.datetime
Left Join 
    table_c On a.emp_id = c.emp_id;


/*solution II*/

Select
     a.id
    ,a.datetime
    ,a.emp_id
    ,c.team_id
From 
    table_b as b
Left Join  
    table_a as a On a.id = b.id
                 And a.datetime <> b.datetime
Left Join 
    table_c On a.emp_id = c.emp_id;

/*Updated solution, based on the comments (requirements seem to have changed)*/

Select
     a.id
    ,a.datetime
    ,a.emp_id
    ,c.team_id
From 
    table_b as b
Left Join  
    table_a as a On a.id = b.id
Left Join 
    table_c On a.emp_id = c.emp_id
WHERE (a.datetime <> b.datetime OR b.datetime IS NULL);
```

> Explanation of the updated solution: there was nothing to take into account the rows which would not match, hence the OR in the join

Please see Microsoft documentation on joins below.

> [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Joins%20indicate%20how%20SQL%20Server,be%20used%20for%20the%20join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Joins%20indicate%20how%20SQL%20Server,be%20used%20for%20the%20join).

Comment: Thanks Eli for this, which does the job. Now the requirement has changed where I need to remove the matching records (by same ID & date/time). Is there a way around this?

Comment: pleasure. Do you need to simply select all from table B where there's no matching record in table A? Just want to make sure that I understand your question

Comment: Yes that is correct Eli (you're much better explaining than I am!)

Comment: Interesting - as you're not selecting any fields from table B. Will all rows be blank then? Best would be if you can put in some sample data and what you expect the results to be.

Comment: Sample data has been added, hopefully this will be clear. I don't want that 'duplicate' row to show or show blank

Comment: @Rockshah based on your desired output, you want all records from Table A where there's no match in Table B. the issue with your query, is that you likely got only 3 records  - I'll update the answer with my "updated answer"